# Why does VS.NET 2013 create a dll file in the bin directory when I build my HTML5 Typescript project?

Tags: .net, html, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I installed the Typescript extension for VS.NET 2013. I had the web development components installed and I can write typescript code, it builds to a single JS file. It works great.

However, it seems like the project is setup to build a bin/MyProjectName.dll file. There's even an option to target a specific version of the .NET framework within the Typescript project. My question is: why? Isn't Typescript supposed to be only for compiling to JS and that's it. What can I do with this DLL file?

Comment: The same for VS2015.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it's because Typescript is not a mature product yet. They are leveraging the existing class library to help us partition our modules, but as a result, you still get an empty DLL in the bin directory. This DLL is pointless and you can safely ignore it.

If you want to kill this auto-generated DLL, then remove that specific project from the [build configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676765.aspx).

Comment: This is correct - it was way less work for us to piggyback on the existing template than to make a new TypeScript project type.

Comment: It takes a bit of time to recompile this empty dll. Is there a way not to run the C# compiler when compiling a TypeScript project?